# Why does the "Back" button on the browser trigger the last activated event?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, events, back

I have 2 webpage, webpage A and webpage B.

**What webpage A does**

Webpage A have 2 event, Page_Load event and button_click event.

When Page_Load event is triggered it will check if user is `logged in` or not, if user is `logged in` it will redirect user to webpage B directly, if not nothing will happen.

When the button on webpage A is clicked, the user stats will become `logged in` and redirect to webpage B.

**What webpage B does**

Webpage B have Page_Load event only.

When Page_Load event is triggered it will check if the user is `logged in` or not, if the user is `logged in` it will stay at the webpage, and if it is not it will redirect back to webpage A.

The problem I am facing right now is, if I load webpage A in `not logged in` stats, click the button proceed to webpage B and click the browser's back button on the top left of the browser, it will proceed to webpage A and trigger the button_click event (which is the last triggered event on webpage A) instead of the Page_Load event which the user is in `logged in` stats but is not redirected to webpage B.

PS. Webpage A's Page_Load event is not triggered at all when user press the back button.

PSS. Both my event is written in C#(asp.net).

What is the cause of this and how do I fix this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found out that this problem only occurs when my webpage A's button_click event occur once but doesn't redirect (try to login but login failed/denied). Then on the second click it worked, proceed to webpage B, right now if click back the fail condition will be shown and Page_Load event not triggered. I feel like this is something to do with cache or Ram? Is there anyway to let my webpage "forget" it failed once and goes back to webpage A as nothing happened before?

Comment: I am not sure if this should matter. How are you jumping to the 2nd page? Do you use Resonse.Redirect("MyPageB.aspsx").

Comment: Yes, I use Response.Redirect() to redirect the user to another page.